# PendingIntent and Notification Intent

Tags: android, android-intent, android-pendingintent

I find the code below redundant. Am I missing something basic here ? Is there a way to reduce the duplicate code here. Can I use either Intent or PendingIntent object, why both ?

```
    Intent updateUI = new Intent(SENDTOBACKGROUND_SERVICE);
    updateUI.putExtra("Signal", God.YELLOW);
    sendBroadcast(updateUI);

    Intent sendNotification = new Intent(DriverService.this, DriverHome.class);
    sendNotification.putExtra("Signal", God.YELLOW);

    PendingIntent pIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(getApplicationContext(), 0, sendNotification, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

    Notification n = new NotificationCompat.Builder(DriverService.this)
            .setContentTitle("Attempting to update location")
            .setContentText("Cab @(last) " + currentLocationInText)
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.yellow).setContentIntent(pIntent).setAutoCancel(true)
            .build();

    ((NotificationManager) DriverService.this.getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE)).notify("Taxeeta", R.id.cabLocation, n);
```

Comment: The PendingIntent enables the ability to run your code with your permissions in another app that perhaps lacks such permissions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you need both. A `PendingIntent` is a wrapper around an `Intent`. You can't have a `PendingIntent` without an `Intent` to wrap. And you can't put an `Intent` in a `Notification`. You need to use a `PendingIntent` when you want to hand over an `Intent` to another component, so that the other component can send the `Intent` for you (as a kind of "proxy") at some point in the future.

Answer (score 1):

As explain in the doc

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/PendingIntent.html#getActivity%28android.content.Context,%20int,%20android.content.Intent,%20int%29

"Retrieve a PendingIntent that will start a new activity, like calling Context.startActivity(Intent)" so you need PendingIntent and Intent.

Comment: as a token of thanks for a good answer, I have also +1 another answer of yours. I accepted David's answer since he answered before.